# How to insert a cloumn of type Blob into Data base using slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following table :

```
class ExampleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Example](tag, "example") {

  def id      = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def content = column[Blob]("content")

  def * = (id, content).mapTo[Example]
}
case class Example(id:Long ,content: Blob)
```

I used the **serialBlob** class but I got an exception in run time.

```
val blob = new SerialBlob(fileInbytes)
```

The exception is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

How to insert a file of type Blob into Data Base?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there looks like it should work in terms of `Blob`.

However, the error (`ConnectionHandle cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`) looks suspicious. Double-check your dependencies to ensure you have the right Oracle driver, and that you have imported the `slick.jdbc.OracleProfile.api._`

In case it helps, it's possibly more common to define a table and case class in terms of `Array[Byte]`, rather than `Blob`. Slick has built-in conversions to take an `Array[Byte]` and treat it as a `Blob` when creating a schema and querying.